# How can I print in grayscale/low quality on my networked Cannon ip4300 via Ubuntu?

Tags: printing, ubuntu-10.04, cups, grayscale

I have a Cannon Pixma ip4300 printer connected to a Mac OS X system and shared using CUPS. I can print to this printer from my Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid workstation just fine, however when printing (specifically from Thunderbird) I don't have the option to print in grayscale or in "low quality"/"draft" mode. How can I enable these options to help save on printing costs?

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following to the ppd file for the printer in `/etc/cups/ppd/` is what is normally done to enable grayscale support on Pixmas. After cups is restarted (/etc/init.d/cups restart) it results in a Grayscale checkbox on the Advanced tab of e.g. evince and firefox:

```
OpenUI *CNGrayscale/Grayscale: Boolean
*DefaultCNGrayscale: False
*CNGrayscale True/Yes: True
*CNGrayscale False/No: False
*CloseUI: *CNGrayscale
```

There are other possibilities - see e.g. http://www.gentooser.shekalug.org/2010/03/enable-the-grayscale-printing-in-a-canon-ip1800-with-cups/